# What's the difference between * and ? in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

Both seem to mean, match 0 or more characters? I don't understand the difference between them, or when to use `?` and when to use `*`. Some examples would help.

Comment: If you are using the * and ? in the context of regular expression then `*` it would match min 0 times and max 1 time the character which immediately precedes the ?. And A `*` will match min 0 times and max any number of times the character which immediately precedes then *.
In the context of glob/wild cards,  `?` would match exactly one character at that position, and it can be any character (does not have to be the preceding). And a `*` would match any number of any characters in that position where the * appears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- In the **Formal** definition the symbols of regular expressions operators are

  `.` : which is concatenation like a.b.c would match a text having abc . Some times to indicate concatenation simply two symbols are used back to back.

  `*` : match the last symbol 0 or more times, (abc)* would match a null string, abc, abcabc, abcabcabc, but not abcaabc. Known as the Kleen's star.

  `+` : would match either the left-hand side or the right hand side . (abc + def) would match abc or def. Also the union operator or the `|` operator is used.

  These are applied on a set of symbols *sigma*, which includes the symbols in your language within other special symbols are the *epsilon* which denotes the empty string, and the *null* means no symbols at all. For details see [[3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/053494728X)]

  These are the **formal** definitions.

When you use applications accepting the POSIX regular expression syntax the meaning of the different operators are like this:

- These are the **POSIX Basic regular expression** operations

  `.` : The dot '.' matches any character like a.c could match abc, axc, amc, aoc anything.

  `^` : Indicates the start of line.  `^abc` would match the string which is starting at the line. abc appearing in between the line would not be matched

  `$` : Indicates the end of line. `abc$` would only match the string abc at the end of the line. This would not match any 'abc' in between the lines.

  `*` : Matches the last symbol preceding the '*' 0 or more times. So `ab*c` would match ac, abc, abbc, abbbc, abbbbbc, abbbbbbbbc etc.

  `{m, n}` : Matches the the preceding symbol atleat 'm' times and at most 'n' times.
  `ab{2,4}c` would *not* match 'abc', but would match 'abbc', 'abbbc', 'abbbbc', but will *not* match 'abbbbbc' . So if the number of 'b' is >= 2 and <= 4 it would match.

  `{m,}` : means match the preceding symbol minimum 'm' times, and no limit in the maximum. (note the comma)

  `{n}` : means match the preceding symbol exactly 'n' times. so `ab{3}c` would only match 'abbbc'.

  `[symbols]` : will match any one of the symbols inside the box braces. like `a[xyz]c` would match 'axc' , 'ayc', and 'azc'  and no other strings

  `[^symbols]` : will match any symbol once which are *not* inside the box brackets. like `a[xyz]c` would match any strings 'a.b' with the '.' being any symbol *except* x, y, z.
- These are the **POSIX Extended regular expression** operators (needs `grep -E`)

  `?` : Will match the preceding symbol 0 or at most 1 time. so `ab?c` would match 'ac' and 'abc' only.

  `+` : Will match the preceding symbol at least 1 time and at most any number times (no upper bounds). Like `ab+c` would match abc, abbbc, abbbbbc, abbbbbbbbc, etc, but would *not* match 'ac'

  `|` : Would match either the expression on the left side of the '|' or the right side expression on the right side of the '|'.  like `(ab+c)|(xy*z)` .
- Also have a look at the **POSIX meta character** classes like `[:alpha:]` represents all the alphabets. `[:punct:]` denotes all the punctuations etc.
- Wild Characters/ Globs
  If you are using `*` and `?` as wild cards then the interpretations are as below

  `*` : Match any number of any characters at this position. Like `*.c` means all strings ending with the string '.c' (here . has no special interpretations) . Test with `ls *.c` or `ls *.doc`

  `?` : Match any character only one time at this position. Like `file??.txt` would match strings 'fileab.c', 'file00.c' etc, and match any exactly two characters. Test with `ls *.???` which will list all the files having a three character extension.

I hope this answers your question. Or you might want to through some text about formal definitions and the POSIX and maybe the Perl style regular expressions for a clear idea.

References:
[Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

[grep manual Regular expression section](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions)

[Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/053494728X)

**Note:** *This answer was reconstructed*

Comment: So, `(abc)?` would match `abc, abcd, abce, abcf` etc but not `abcdef`?

Comment: If ? is used as a glob/wild card then it would only match only a 4 character string with abc and any one letter after abc. If you use ? with grep extended regular expression then ? would match the preceeding character at most one time. so abc?d would match abd, abcd

Comment: `.` isn't concenation, it's any single character, `+` mathes the previous character/expression (if using braces) one or more times.

Comment: Yes the `.` does match any character according to the POSIX syntax [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) 
If you have a look at the formal definition then `.` means concatenation, or simply writing two symbols back to back also means concatenation.

Comment: Your explanation to `.` and `+` is simply wrong. See @icktoofay and @manojlds for the correct answer ==> -1. [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a wonderful site to learn about regexes.

Comment: If you have read the answer i have wrote what is the **formal** definition of a regular expression and it has nothing to do with any specific language, it is a type of Type You are talking about POSIX regular expressions. What you have linked and told is also correct because the interpretation of the '+' and the '.' is different. `.` means match any symbol and `+` means the last symbol one or more times. Probably i am unable to convey what i want to tell. I would edit the post ans include some more information to avoid confusions.

Comment: I have reconstructed the answer i hope not i am clear what i want to say.

Comment: @phoxis, respect for the effort you spent in this answer (undo -1), but I still do not agree with your part about "formal" regular expressions. I think this is something completely different from the definition of regular languages in formal language theory, and has nothing to do with the regular expressions used in our programming languages. And the tag regex here in SO is for those regexes practically used.

Comment: @stema : The formal definitions which i gave are of the regular expressions and are not the regular languages which allow A->Ab transitions (type 3 productions in Chomsky Classification). The basic regular expression is actually recursively recursively defined,a regular expressio is either an empty string a null string or a symbol from the alphabet, then it is recursively stated that the Union or sometimes denoted by +,the Kleen's Star * and the concatenation. operations on these are also regular expressions, and these operations are are closed under the alphabet, and are the basic definition.

Comment: @stema: I would like you to please confirm form some text on what the formal definition. I agree that this definition is official and in real application the syntax are different and most follow the POSIX syntax. But the formal definition operators are the *basic* operators and are minimal. Note that a lot of the POSIX operators can be derived from the formal definition basic operators, but they are complex.
What i want is a correct answer. Thanks for commenting and helping to improve the answer.

Answer (score 8):

`?` means zero or one of. `*` means any number of. So this:

```
^ab?$
```

would match `a` and `ab`, but not `abb`. This:

```
^ab*$
```

would match not only `a` and `ab`, but also `abb`, `abbb`, and `a` with any number of `b`s following it.

Comment: Nitpicking: `ab?` would match the letters `ab` of `abb`; it would not match the second `b`.  If the regexp were `^ab?$`, then it would not match `abb`.  For completeness, you could also mention `ab+` which would not match `a` but would match `ab`, `abb`, `abbb`, and so on (matching one or more of the item).

Comment: What if i put `[ab]?`, will that be valid and what will that do?

Comment: It will match nothing, "a", or "b".

Comment: @rmhh Then in what kind of situation would you want to use `?`? It seems useless..

Comment: When you want to have an optional part that may appear only once, as in `That's a nice colou?r`. You wouldn't want to use *, as that would match `Thats a nice colouuuuuur`.

Answer (score 4):

For sake of regex completeness something like `*?` is also used. In this case it is a lazy match or non-greedy match and will match as few characters as possible before matching the next token.

For example:

```
a.*a
```

would match whole of abaaba

while

```
a.*?a
```

will match `aba`, `aba`